# How can I change data source in graphics in Power BI without starting over again?

Tags: graphics, powerbi

I'm very new in Power BI. I made a report, but as time went on I had to transform data before insert them in PowerBI. So now I need to change the source of my data in graphics (like we can do in Excel for example). If I change this field by field, I had to update colors,... Is it possible to change data without starting over again ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can do it, but you need to be aware that the old source and the new source had the same information. I mean if you have a field A in your old source database, that you transform in the new database it should be named A like before, and with the same datatype, over wise you will need to review your data importation rules.

However to do this go on the tab "Home" then click on "Edit Queries" drop down menu and select the "Data Source Settings"

[Power BI Data Source Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3Ibb.png)

Another way to do this is to edit the query with the "Edit Queries" button and then on the right hand side click on source in the Applied Steps area.
[Applied Steps area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VqOh.png)

I hope that I answered to your question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! In fact, I need to change the source of data for one graphic for example. Sometimes I need to change the structure of my data (add a column, drop an other) so I can’t « just » update the table. Do you think it’s possible ?

Comment: Hello MarieT, you can do this but you have to be aware that when you remove a column on which you did some transformation you will run into an error. Anyway to do this you need to go to the "Query Editor" and click the "Advanced Editor" button. This will open a window where you can see all the steps of your data importation/transformation. Everything in there is written in M language, but it's pretty intuitive to play with.

Comment: Playing with advanced editor works, thank you for your advice !

Answer (score 1):

I think I had a similar problem a while ago, when the database my Power BI report referred to was moved.

What I did (in Power BI Desktop app, using Direct Query) was under "Home" clicking on the drop-down menu "Edit Queries" at the top left corner, then selecting "Data source settings". In the new window I clicked the button "Change source settings". Then I changed the settings to the new location of the server and database. See the attached link (including a picture) for information. [detailed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmAUN.jpg)

Comment: Excuse me, my question wasn't clear, I can't add a column and do what you do after without play with the advanced editor, but yes, we can update data like this